# How to get scaled image size Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am able to get the actual image height from [here](https://reformatcode.com/code/dart/how-do-i-determine-the-width-and-height-of-an-image-in-flutter)
However, I am looking for a way to get the actual height of the image that has been scaled on different device screens.

Comment: Could you provide some more details: what are you trying to do with the scaled image dimensions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio` combined with the size in DP of your image container.